# How to remove UAC sheild Icon

Tags: uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Remove UAC Icon Overlays (Blue-Yellow Shields) in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/68345/how-to-remove-uac-icon-overlays-blue-yellow-shields-in-windows-7)

How can we remove the (yellow-blue) UAC icon that overlay on our executable files without changing UAC Settings or compromising on security? Also how to avoid that pop-up message that says you need administrative writes to continue.

Comment: Good question. The whole point of UAC is to prevent what you're trying to do. It would be interesting to see if it's possible.