# How to undo changes in command prompt?

Tags: cmd.exe, icons, desktop-icons, undo

*I do not know anything about computer coding, so a detailed answer to the solution would be great!*

I followed [these](https://superuser.com/q/68345/529800) instructions not knowing what it would do and, in the top answer, the person suggested to execute the following, but now all of my icons have been deleted:

```bat
TaskKill /IM "Explorer.exe" /F
Cd /d "%LocalAppData%"
Del "IconCache.db" /a
Shutdown /r
```

- I've tried performing a system restore, but it would not change anything

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply undo that. You've deleted the icon cache file and this is irreversible but this should not be a problem because Windows should rebuild it automatically when you restart your computer.

Did you already do that?

Maybe something else went wrong.

Comment: yes ive done that and it didnt rebuild anything.  all of my icons stored has been deleted and any new icons will not show up

Comment: @Michael I tried this solution on a Win10 computer and nothing happened. Which Windows Versiob are you running?