All icons missing from desktop and explorer
All icons disappeared when was trying to Remove UAC Icon Overlays (Blue-Yellow Shields).
I followed these instructions ; https://superuser.com/a/356301/2165882
Disable UAC [User Account Control] by moving its slider to the lowest position
Open Command Prompt (you'll find it in the Start Menu)
Execute the following, pressing Enter after each line:
TaskKill /IM "Explorer.exe" /F

cd /D "%LocalAppData%"

del "IconCache.db" /A

Shutdown /R

Tried rebuilding iconcache through .dat and command prompt. Didn't work. Can't find iconcache.dbms  file... (view hidden files is on)
Also tried Clean boot and Safe Mode...
Driving me mad, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

You are aware it actually is NOT possible to disable UAC they you have attempted to disable it? Is there a reason you deleted your entire LocalAppData directory? I assume you have tried to restart File Explorer? You followed really bad advice
