# Windows 10: fix shortcut's empty overlay?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, file-corruption

My shortcuts are really weird: it have a 'empty shortcut icon' overlay.

This only happen on shortcut files aka *.lnk files

An example: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcXak.png)

Do you know how to fix that?

Technical details:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro x64
- Recent action: update drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below articles and thread which describe the similar issue as yours.

You need to check registry key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons**

Delete below REG_SZ Item named 29 and restart the computer.
[image]

For your reference:

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-overlapping-icon-windows-7-vista/

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-modify-shortcut-overlay-windows-7-vista/

[Remove shortcut icon overlay from shortcuts on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/11931/remove-shortcut-icon-overlay-from-shortcuts-on-windows-7)